# Is there a way to remove a flag?

Tags: support, questions

My question is pretty straightfoward. I flagged [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/69433/why-are-the-envelopes-for-the-academy-awards-all-in-the-same-color) as a duplicate, but realized later it wasn't actually a duplicate.

Is there a way for me to remove the flag? Or only moderators can do this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you retract the flag? Go to the flag pane again, and click "retract flag".

Comment: Frankly it is a duplicate (essentially) and unanswerable anyway. I wouldn't worry, It'll be closed soon enough.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is a way.

If you flag something and realize that it was a wrong flag, you can again click on **flag** link.

It will show the type of flag you raised. At the bottom right, there is a button saying *Retract Flag*.

You can click on it and your flag will be retracted.

But remember, you cannot flag it same as before after retracting.

Comment: There was no retract flag button for me at the time. But I now the question was closed as off topic.